# How to identify the third column of the third table for MS Word macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to figure out if I can set the range of a range variable in MS Word VB for applications to the third column of the third table in a MS Word document.

So far, this is as close as I can get without my code breaking:

```
Set range = ActiveDocument.Tables(3).range
```

Is there any way for me to put in a reference to Columns(3) in there without the debugger going crazy?

My code so far:

```
Set range = ActiveDocument.Tables(3).range
With range.Find
    .Text = "Passed"
    .Format = True 
    .MatchCase = True
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
        iCount = iCount + 1
    Loop
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like ... ?

```
Dim col As Column
Set col = ActiveDocument.Tables(3).Columns(3)
col.Cells(1).Range.Text = "Abc"
Debug.Print col.Cells(1).Range.Text
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But how do I make the Cells(1) dynamic? In other words, make it so that the range isn't limited to the first cell in the third column, but all the cells in the column?

Comment: `For Each c col.Cells` would be one way.